# Double struck f in combinatorics graph theory

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm just getting confused in this question below about the mathematical symbol

[image]

> Let $H_{n}=\left(V_{n}, E_{n}\right)$ be the hypercube graph from Problem Sheet $5,$ that is, $V_{n}=\mathbb{F}_{2}^{n}$ and $E_{n}=\left\{x y: x, y \in V_{n}, d(x, y)=1\right\},$ where $d$ is the Hamming distance on $\mathbb{F}_{2}^{n}$

Could anyone give me any hints? Thank you!

Comment: $\Bbb F_2$ is the two-element field; $\Bbb F_2^n$ is therefore the set of binary $n$-tuples, with addition mod $2$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott rlly sry but I got one more question. Does this symbol stand for a type of hypercube graph? How do I count the edge of this graph? Thank you so much!

Comment: $\Bbb F_2^n$ is the set of vertices of the $n$-dimensional hypercube; two vertices are adjacent if they differ in exactly one coordinate.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Can I use the handshaking lemma to calculate the number of edge? i.e. 1/2 * 2^n(which is the degree of v) * n = IEI

Comment: Yes; your calculation is correct.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks! Does n has to be mod 2?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. Using the set of $n$-place vectors with coordinates in $\Bbb F_2$ is just an easy way to describe the hypercube graph formed by the vertices and edges of an $n$-dimensional hypercube. For $n=1,2$, and $3$ you can even draw pictures showing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a community wiki answer so the question can be closed:

> $\mathbb{F}_2$ is the [field of two elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GF%282%29). Therefore $\mathbb{F}_2^n = \underbrace{\mathbb{F}_2 \times \cdots \times \mathbb{F}_2}_{n\ \text{times}}$ is the $n$-dimensional $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space consisting of all binary $n$-tuples with addition modulo 2.